# Bash wrapper for fortran code

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I have a fortran code (wrote by somebody else - cannot change it...) that takes an input parameter file, executes it, then has an interactive prompt. This is how it works:

```
[user@host] ./mycode

Welcome; what is the file name? _
```

Once you give it the param file and hit enter, the program executes it and prompts options:

```
OPTIONS  a=add something
         u=undo
         o=overplot
         q=quit
```

You then interact with the code, and quit. The problem I have is that every time I quit the program and have to start over, I have to keep re-typing the param file name (which is a pain for long names). I would like to write a simple shell-script that would do:

```
./mycode_auto param_file
```

Then it would execute the param_file and give the prompt with options. My first naive attempt, which I knew it was missing something:

```
#!/bin/bash

./mycode << EOF

$1

EOF
```

It opens `mycode`, executes the param file, but breaks right after, and I get:

```
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

I can actually understand what it happening, but don't know a way around it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can not modify the fortran program, I believe your only solution will be to use [expect](/questions/tagged/expect). Have a look at the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#we store the content of our 1st argument
set file_path [lindex $argv 0]

#process we need to interract with
spawn ./mycode

#if we encounter this message ...
expect "Welcome; what is the file name?" {
    #... we send it our first argument
    send "$file_path\r"
}
#we resume normal interaction with our script
interact
```

Simply call it like that : `script.expect "/path/to/file"`, assuming the expect script and `mycode` are in the same folder.

Comment: my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Wow, I guess it could have not worked better than it did! Many thanks!